# Angularjs bootstrap typeahead not working: Error: [filter:notarray]

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I need to fetch suggest options using typeahead making a http call

```
$scope.getlist = function getListofNames(name) {
 return $http({
   method: 'GET',
     url: '/v1/'+name,
     data: ""
 }).then(function(response){

     if(response.data.statusMessage !== 'SUCCESS'){
         response.errorMessage = "Error while processing request. Please retry."
           return response;
     }

         else {
           return response.data.payload;
         }

       }, function(response){
       response.errorMessage = "Error while processing request"
           return response;
       }
       );
}
```

response.data.payload is an array of objects , It is fetched successfully but I am getting this error 
Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/filter/notarray?

Note : I am using angular 1.4.5 and Bootstrap v3.1.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing your typeahead markup looks like this:

```
<input [...] typeahead="item in getItems($viewValue) | filter: $viewValue">
```

#### Why it is not working:

The problem occurs when the array of items is **fetched asynchronously**. In your case the `getItems` function is called `getListofNames`, and your items are indeed fetched asynchronously, due to the call to `$http`. Therefore at the time the error occurs, *getListofNames()* is still an unresolved **promise object**, not yet an array of names.

#### How could you make that work:

Remove the filter from the template. You should filter the array before returning it in `getItems`. **Ideally, you want to do the filtering server-side**. Indeed, the server receives the substring typed by the user (this is the `$viewValue` argument), and therefore it has all the data to filter the array. That would prevent returning all the elements and make the response shorter.
Alternatively, you could filter client-side in the callback of the promise:

```
$scope.getList = function getListofNames(name) {
    return $http(...}).then(
        function(response){
            // filter response.data.payload according to 
            // the 'name' ($viewValue) substring entered by the user
            return filteredArray; // <- no need to pipe a filter in the template anymore
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: That was a breakthrough!

Comment: One more thing since 1.3.3 ng it doesn't support promise unwrapping. That's why it's sees the promise object and not the resolved array.